# Is the beach of an island considered a shore?

Tags: meaning, terminology, speech

If not, what is it called? I'd like to know because I am making a literary comment on this word and I need its exact definition.

Answer (score 1):

The edge of any land bordering on a body of water is a shore.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shore?s=t

There are other words you might find useful, such as coastline, coast, waterfront, etc.